# Python issue in writing file to pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with pdf content in python and my input from a service response is of the type  _io.BufferedRandom. I need to save this file as pdf within my service for further usage

```
response = open('test_file.pdf', 'rb+')
```

this is the input to my service and is of the type _io.BufferedRandom

```
with open('output.pdf', 'wb+') as f:
    f.write(response)
```

doing this I get the error - TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedRandom'

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Try `f.write(response.read())`

Answer (score 0):

As an open method return the file object to open a file for reading/write or append. like

```
open(filename, mode)

f = open('workfile', 'w')
```

and in your case, you try to write file object to another file, not the content

```
f.write(response)
```

So you will need to use read function as

f.read(size) - read file and return a string (in text mode) or bytes object (in binary mode).

so the final procedure will be

```
with open('output.pdf', 'wb+') as f:
    f.write(response.read())
```